# If $f_n \to f$ in probability, then $\sup E|f_n| < \infty \Rightarrow E|f| < \infty$.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose that $f_n,f$ are random variables such that $f_n \to f$ in probability. I want to show that
$$
\forall p > 0: \sup_n E|f_n|^p < \infty \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \forall p > 0: E|f|^p < \infty.
$$

My try: Pick a subsequence such that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$ a.e. Then also $|f_{n_k}|^p \to|f|^p$ a.e. and now I am not sure how to continue, maybe using Lebesgue?

Comment: Dominated convergence is good, but you need to be a bit careful since we can't use $f$ to build the dominating function.   You'll need to use $g(x) = f_n(x) + \epsilon$ for an appropriate $n$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What if $f_n=n^2\chi_{(1/(n+1),1/n)}$ on $(0,1)?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this doesn't work, because, in general, we don't have a pointwise dominating function which is integrable. However, Fatou's lemma does the job. Applying Fatou's lemma gives

$$\mathbb{E}(|f|^p) = \mathbb{E} \left(\liminf_{k \to \infty} |f_{n_k}|^p \right) \stackrel{\text{Fatou}}{\leq} \liminf_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|f_{n_k}|^p) \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}(|f_n|^p)<\infty$$ where we have used that $$\liminf_{k \to \infty} f_{n_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} f_{n_k} = f.$$